# How to change <input> tag value to default if user enters less than specified value?

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML form, there are 3 input tags. The type of input tag has been set to number. The form is working well for calculating sum of 3 inputs.
But the problem arises when user enters negative values in input. Therefore, I want my code to change values entered in input tag to default of those where user has entered a value less than 0. The action should be performed when input `type="button"` is clicked.

Here is my code:

```html
<HTML>
<head><title>Calculation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

   PE Ratio
    <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
    
  ROCE  
    <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
   
  Sales Growth 
     <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
    
   <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="amount.value = (15 -( PE.valueAsNumber/2)) + (40 - (ROCE.valueAsNumber)) + (10-(SG.valueAsNumber))">
  
   <p>Rating: <div id="div1">
   <strong><output name="amount" for="hours rate vat">0</output></strong></div>
   </p>
     </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

for (PE) ID input, default value is 7
for (ROCE) ID input, default value is 5
for ( SG) id input, dafault value is 4

I am not sure how should I do this.

Comment: Have you read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation?

Answer (score 0):

How I will do it is 
First make a javascript file like abc.js
write the following code in it

```
function corrector(){
var x = document.getElementById("PE").value;
var y = document.getElementById("ROCE").value;
var z = document.getElementById("SG").value;
if(x<0)
x=7;
if(y<0)
y=5;
if(z<0)
z=4;
}
```

Now include the js file in the main html file
Include the rest of the logic in this js file only.

```
 <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; 
 top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="corrector()">
```

Comment: Where I have to add rest of the logic??? Please tell me through a complete HTML code....

Comment: just add your logic in the corrector function after the last if condition

Comment: Like var ans = 15 - x/2 + 40-y + 10-z

Comment: I tried  to add var ans =15- x/2 + 40-y + 10-z after last if condition....but it is not working....I don't have enough knowledge of JavaScript..... So, can you please edit your code according to my question and give me the full answer..............thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

It helps to separate out your code from your markup - I moved the `onclick` logic to a `calculate` function which does the validation you want. I also simplified your math.

```js
function calculate() {
  const defaults = {PE: 7, ROCE: 5, SG: 4};
  const values = {};
  Object.keys(defaults).forEach(id => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.value < 0) {
      el.value = defaults[id];
    }
    values[id] = el.value;
  });
  document.getElementsByName('amount')[0].value = 65 - values.PE/2 - values.ROCE - values.SG
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<head><title>Calculation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  PE Ratio
    <input type="number" min="0" id="PE" /><br>
    
  ROCE  
    <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
   
  Sales Growth 
     <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
    
   <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="calculate()">
  
   <p>Rating: <div id="div1">
   <strong><output name="amount" for="hours rate vat">0</output></strong></div>
   </p>
     </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I think you have an error. You should compare input value with 0 and use default if it's less then 0.

Comment: Your code is working well....but my formula or logic for calculating sum was different...and you used a complete different method....I tried to change your logic as per my convince, but after that code is giving very different output....please edit your code and make sure the logic remain same...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that when all your code is thrown into an HTML form. I removed the form (if you really need it, tell me and I'll change the code). I also changed your form code into simpler JavaScript code.

I made it so that you can just copy & paste the code into one script.

If something doesn't work the way you want to. Let me know.

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Calculation</title>
</head>

<body>

  PE Ratio <input type="number" id="PE" /><br> ROCE <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br> Sales Growth <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br>

  <button onsubmit="return false" onclick="Multiply()" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;" onsubmit="return false">Multiply</button>

  <p>Rating</p>
  <b id="output">0</b>
</body>
<script>
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  function Multiply() {

    var a = isNaN(PE.valueAsNumber) ? 7 : PE.valueAsNumber;
    var b = isNaN(ROCE.valueAsNumber) ? 5 : ROCE.valueAsNumber;
    var c = isNaN(SG.valueAsNumber) ? 4 : SG.valueAsNumber;

    if (PE.valueAsNumber < 0 || SG.valueAsNumber < 0 || ROCE.valueAsNumber < 0)
      output.innerHTML = "No negetive numbers"
    else
      output.innerHTML = 15 - a / 2 + 40 - b + 10 - c;
  }
</script>

</HTML>
```

Comment: I changed the code, but I wasn't quite sure what you needed. I deleted the `value` in the `input` fields but made it so if you leave the `input` fields blank it would still use the `default` value.